# Help understanding segfault with std::map/boost::unordered_map

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, segmentation-fault, unordered-map

I have some code to handle resource (images, fonts, mesh data, etc.) management using a template'd static class, allowing client code to do something like:

```
ResourceManager<Texture>::init("data/textures");
ResourceManager<Font>::init("data/fonts");
// later ...
boost::shared_ptr<const Texture> tex = ResourceManager<Texture>::getResource("wall.png");
boost::shared_ptr<const Font> font = ResourceManager<Font>::getResource("Arial.ttf");
// later ...
ResourceManager<Texture>::release();
```

The "resource type" must have a constructor taking a `const std::string&`.

`getResource` is implemented as follows:

```
static boost::shared_ptr<const ResourceType> getResource(const std::string& fileName)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<ResourceType> resource;

    typename table_t::const_iterator itr = _resources.find(fileName);
    if (itr == _resources.end()) {
        resource.reset(new ResourceType(_dataDirectory + fileName));
        _resources[fileName] = resource;
    } else {
        resource = itr->second;
    }

    return resource;
}
```

`table_t` is defined as `typedef typename boost::unordered_map< std::string, boost::shared_ptr<ResourceType> > table_t;`

`_resources` is of type `table_t`.

The problem is with `boost::unordered_map` I get a segfault on the call to `find` (originating from `find_iterator`). However, with `std::map` instead, I either get a segfault on the insert operation (originating from `_Rb_tree_decrement`), or on the call to `find` (originating from `string::compare`).

<strike>The problem only occurs the **2nd** time a resource is requested (fileName is valid when the failure occurs).</strike>

As this is happening with both `map` and `unordered_map` I'm assuming I must be doing something bizarre somewhere to cause this, any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT: Still having the problem, I was wrong about it only happening the 2nd time a resource is requested. However, the first 2 calls to get a resource are successful, it's the 3rd call that is causing the segfault (each call is for a different resource).

Here is a stack trace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004b4978 in boost::unordered_detail::hash_table<boost::unordered_detail::map<std::string, boost::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, boost::shared_ptr<Texture> > > > >::find_iterator (this=0x7aed80, bucket=0x38, k=...)
    at /usr/local/include/boost/unordered/detail/table.hpp:55
55          node_ptr it = bucket->next_;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004b4978 in boost::unordered_detail::hash_table<boost::unordered_detail::map<std::string, boost::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, boost::shared_ptr<Texture> > > > >::find_iterator (this=0x7aed80, bucket=0x38, k=...)
    at /usr/local/include/boost/unordered/detail/table.hpp:55
#1  0x00000000004b294c in boost::unordered_detail::hash_table<boost::unordered_detail::map<std::string, boost::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, boost::shared_ptr<Texture> > > > >::find (this=0x7aed80, k=...)
    at /usr/local/include/boost/unordered/detail/table.hpp:583
#2  0x00000000004b07c1 in boost::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<Texture>, boost::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, boost::shared_ptr<Texture> > > >::find (this=0x7aed80, k=...)
    at /usr/local/include/boost/unordered/unordered_map.hpp:423
#3  0x00000000004ae7c6 in ResourceManager<Texture>::getResource (fileName=...) at /home/tim/Projects/gameproj/app/ResourceManager.hpp:52
#4  0x00000000004ce7fc in Map::loadCellTextures (this=0x7fffffffdfc0, in=...) at /home/tim/Projects/gameproj/app/Map.cpp:57
#5  0x00000000004ce632 in Map (this=0x7fffffffdfc0, fileName=...) at /home/tim/Projects/gameproj/app/Map.cpp:30
#6  0x0000000000495702 in Game::init (xResolution=1024, yResolution=768) at /home/tim/Projects/gameproj/app/Game.cpp:116
#7  0x0000000000494fa0 in Game::run (xResolution=1024, yResolution=768) at /home/tim/Projects/gameproj/app/Game.cpp:38
#8  0x0000000000487f1d in Main::run (xResolution=1024, yResolution=768) at /home/tim/Projects/gameproj/app/Main.cpp:28
#9  0x0000000000487db5 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe398) at /home/tim/Projects/gameproj/app/main.cpp:10
```

Comment: how is _resources declared/initialized/destroyed/etc?

Comment: adding a backtrace from gdb when the sig11 happens could help diagnose.

Comment: `_resources` is declared as `static table_t _resources;`, and initialized with:

`template <typename ResourceType> boost::unordered_map< std::string, boost::shared_ptr<ResourceType> > ResourceFactory<ResourceType>::_resources;`

below the class definition.

There is a static `release` function which is called to free the resources, this is simply done with `_resources.clear()`.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: Im having a really similar problem with qmake on ubuntu 64.
weird thing is that the same exact code runs great on blackberry 10 (qnx)

Answer (score 2):

I can't spot any obvious errors, have you tried [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (assuming you run some kind of *nix system)? It's an invaluable tool for finding memory errors, and this looks like it might be one of those.

Comment: +1 for recommending valgrind, it is an invaluable tool and well worth your time to learn it.

Comment: I'm somewhat familiar with Valgrind, I receive an 'Invalid read of size 8' when the segfault occurs. The offending line is `node_ptr it = bucket->next_;` in table.hpp (part of boost). With a debugger it appears that `bucket` is dangling/uninitialized.

Comment: @Tim: That's a clue, but I doubt the error is in boost itself. If you give more context someone might be able to spot it.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem only occurs the 2nd time a resource is requested

This suggests to me that your code might be freeing the resource - the first time it's all fine, then you free it, then the next time the container tries to access that memory, it segfaults.

Answer (score 0):

Look i was having a similar problem.
My class worked great on BlackBerry's compiler and qmake 4. but on qtcreator 5 (64 and 32b) i was having the same issue.
i traced this 
http://www.instructables.com/answers/Why-would-an-empty-stdmap-seg-fault-on-the-first/#CXBBGN4GQO92M2Q

looks like the default constructor doesn't initialize correctly on some compiler.
i added a `clear()` on the parent class constructor and now seems to work.

It also can happen if you have some static declarations (or worse extern) and the time in when the map should be instantiated is not the expected.

i hope it helps.